# Replace values of dictionaries (in a list) with a value in list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

below is my list of dictionaries I am working with (I have kept to 2 on purpose):

```
ld= [{'this': 1, 'is': 1, 'the': 1, 'first': 1, 'document': 1}, {'this': 1, 'document': 2, 'is': 1, 'the': 1, 'second': 1}]
```

Below is my list of lists (I have kept to 2 on purpose):

```
b=[[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], [0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666]]
```

The count of dict keys is 10, and the count of values in b is also 10. I want to replace the values in b with dict.values() in list ld with same index value (i.e "this" key in first dict should get the first value in b). How can I achieve this task?

Comment: I also have a list of lists that contains all the keys in the same format:
klist= [['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'document'], ['this', 'document', 'is', 'the', 'second']]
But I dont know how to merge these with the values in b.

Comment: I am calculating tf-idf (Term frequency, inverse document frequency) values for a bunch of sentences. I have IDF values for all the unique words in the sentences and I have all the tf values for each word. Now I need to multiply both of them but cannot find a way to associate the tf values with the words itself. By associating with a dict, I can write a program where I can pull the tf and IDF values by comparing the keys and multiplying the result and stack it in a sparse matrix way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With dictionaries the key order is **not** preserved (**Unless using Python 3.6+**). This means when you try utilise the index of your list items to set values to the order of keys, your data can and will be set to the wrong keys.

Given you commented that you have a secondary list, containing key names. It would be best to use this to map the indexes of your data and keys together, then update your original dictionary with the values.

```
for indx, values in enumerate(b): # For index, and value in list
    data = list(zip(values, klist[indx])) # Zip the elements in your list with the list located at the same index in klist
    for row in data: # For tuple in [(0.2, 'this'), (0.2, 'is'), (0.2, 'the'), (0.2, 'first'), (0.2, 'document')]
        ld[indx][row[1]] = row[0]
```

All of the above will update the values in your original dictonary, insuring that the values in both your lists are mapped to the correct keys, not a random order.

```
#[{'this': 0.2, 'is': 0.2, 'the': 0.2, 'first': 0.2, 'document': 0.2}, {'this': 0.16666666666666666, 'document': 0.3333333333333333, 'is': 0.16666666666666666, 'the': 0.16666666666666666, 'second': 0.16666666666666666}]
```

Comment: Hi @PacketLoss, I am trying to understand the last line (ld[indx][row[1]] = row[0]) but am unable to, why are we taking "ld[indx]" and [row[1]]? I am confused. Would appreciate if you could explain it to me. Thank you.

Comment: `ld`, name of list of dictionary's `id[indx]` this points to the index it is currently iterating over. It is an integer value. In the case of your example it will be `0` and than `1`. `[row[1]]` is pointing to value #1 in the tuple after `zip()` which is the name of the key. `row[0]` is the value you want that key to be set to. So all in all; `ld[0]['this'] = 0.2`

Comment: Damn, sweet explanation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick, inelegant solution:

```py
ld= [{'this': 1, 'is': 1, 'the': 1, 'first': 1, 'document': 1}, {'this': 1, 'document': 2, 'is': 1, 'the': 1, 'second': 1}]

b=[[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2], [0.16666666666666666, 0.3333333333333333, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666, 0.16666666666666666]]

for i, dictionary in enumerate(ld):
    for j, key in enumerate(dictionary):
        dictionary[key] = b[i][j]

print(ld)
```

We loop over the dictionary and index it such that we can reference the list `b` to pull corresponding values.

Using this as a starting point, we can now write a better code using list comprehension.

```py
new_list = [{key: b[i][j]} for i, dictionary in enumerate(ld) for j, key in enumerate(dictionary)]
```

In both cases, we get the expected output:

```py
>>> new_list
[{'this': 0.2}, {'is': 0.2}, {'document': 0.2}, {'the': 0.2}, {'first': 0.2}, {'this': 0.16666666666666666}, {'is': 0.3333333333333333}, {'document': 0.16666666666666666}, {'the': 0.16666666666666666}, {'second': 0.16666666666666666}]
```

I'd be happy to answer any additional questions you might have.

**EDIT**

@PacketLoss's rightly points out that the output of my code messes with the error. Therefore, we might consider an alternate implementation with `collections.OrderedDict`. Concretely,

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

for i, dictionary in enumerate(ld):
    dictionary = OrderedDict(dictionary)
    for j, key in enumerate(dictionary):
        dictionary[key] = b[i][j]
```

This maintains the sequential integrity of the original dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for answering it, I am trying to understand the code now (letting it sink in) and I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: @Aditya No problem. One thing I forgot to mention is that when we enumerate through a list, it gives us the index and the element at that index position; when we enumerate a dictionary, we get the index and the key (not its value). I think this piece of information might help you better understand the code.

Comment: This answer will not work if you are trying to map values at an `index` to a key. key orders are not preserved in dictionaries. When you iterate, the data at `index 1` may not actually be placed into the `key/value pair` in position 1.

Comment: The order is not maintained, look at the result. Your values are in the same index order, however the keys are not. `{'is': 0.3333333333333333}` is the correct value for index 2, however `document` is the key it should have been applied against (Based off your question)

Comment: Actually.. quick question @Aditya, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: Thanks to @PacketLoss for the constructive feedback. I hope everything is clear now, Aditya.

Comment: @JST99 it entirely depends on the version of python. Your code actually works in 3.6+. However anything under does not implement ordered dictionaries by default.

Comment: @PacketLoss I wasn't previously aware of the intricacies of Python version and the implementation of ordered dictionaries, thanks for the heads up.